# 500 error page doesn't show up

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using play 2.2.0
I have a Global object settings defined with methods onError and onHandlerNotFound overridden. From view I am making ajax call which throws 500 internal server due to sql syntax issue, but I am not able to see 500 internal page that I have setup in onError method, but I can see NotFound page if handler is not found. Is it something expected because I am using ajax request.

```
object Global extends WithFilters(LogFilter) with GlobalSettings {
    override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable) = {
        Future.successful(InternalServerError(
            views.html.error(ex)
        ))
    }  
  ...
}
```

Comment: If that's an ajax request, then the question is where do you make the ajax call and what do you do with the results? In other words, could you also post the frontend code that makes this request?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is expected, as your two ajax requests are most likely different (as Ashalynd mentioned, post your frontend code). Where you do your ajax request capture the response and redirect accordingly. E.g. with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://wherever.com",
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(msg) {
      // Do successful things
   },
   error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      // Redirect
      window.location.href = "/errorpage.html";
      // Or some weird form of "redirect" (don't use this, just 
      // for demonstration purpose, showing how you can capture
      // whatever you sent along with your error)
      var responseText = $.httpData(xhr);
      document.body.innerHtml = responseText;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature of Play! 2.2. I have the same problem with Play! 2.2.1, Java API and using curl from command line. It's just that onHandlerNotFound works as specified, but onError just leaves the HTTP connection hanging and never returns a response.

Downgrading to 2.1.5 fixes the problem.